# iwconfig wlan0 ap xx:xx doesn't change my Cell ID?

Tags: raspberry-pi, adhoc, bssid, iwconfig

I have 3 RPI and TP-LINK TL-wr723n V3. I configured it in ad-hoc mode and it works. When I am taking RPI3 of network coverage RPI 1 and 2 lose connection. But when take RPI3 back connection is not restored.
Before it lose connection all 3 PRI has the same Cell in iwconfig wlan0 , after RPI 1,2 has the same Cell but this value different from RPI 3 Cell value.

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"Pi"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Cell: 02:11:87:5E:A4:01
      Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

I want to set Cell ID into unchangeable value. iwconfig wlan0 ap XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX should do it but it change Cell field randomly like: 02:11:87:4B:37:00   02:11:87:2D:3E:00    02:11:87:73:44:00

Why is this happening?

And:
Is it true that Cell field, Cell ID and BSSID is the same things?
Is it true that iwconfig wlan0 ap XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX change exactly Cell ID in ad-hoc mode?

I use Raspbian 
Kernel Linux 3.12.35+ #730 PREEMPT Fri Dec 19 18:31:24 GMT 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux

Answer (score -1):

Don't use ***iwconfig***, it is deprecated. Use ***iw*** instead.